# One noun two adjectives

Tags: grammar, nouns, adjectives, conjunctions

I have two notions that are similar the one is called "full group algebra" and the other "reduced group algebra".

How do I combine those with an "and"? Can I abbreviate it to

"there is the full and reduced group algebra",

or do I have to say "there is the full group algebra and the reduced group algebra"?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to repeat the determiner because of the singular verb form *[there] **is***. If you *don't* want to repeat it, you'd have to say *There **are** the full and reduced group **algebras***, otherwise you'd be implying there's only ***a single type of group algebra***, which is simultaneously both type "full" ***and*** "reduced" group (whatever those terms mean).

Comment: I'd probably go with *there are full group and reduced group algebras* in a formal setting. Some folks will want a hyphen after the *fulls*. If you use the hyphen consistently, you can use *there are full- and reduced-group algebras*. This assumes that a *group algebra* isn't really a thing and the two words aren't working as a compound noun here.

Comment: group algebra is kind of the catch-all term and there is a reduced version and a full version of this object. Therefore I don't quite get your comment @PhilSweet

Comment: Then you probably don't want the hyphenated version. As long as *group algebra* is understood as a thing, Fumble Finger's comment covers it.

Comment: If you actually mean that *group algebra* is a compound noun (group isn't part of the adjective), that's unusual, and you would likely have to use hyphens differently to make that meaning clear: *full and reduced group-algebras*. Regardless of what you mean, you need to put a hyphen somewhere in order to avoid ambiguity. Unless, of course, you rephrase the sentence completely: *there are group alegbras that are full and reduced*.

Comment: @JasonBassford yes, you're right. It's a compund noun. But the ubiquitous writing seems not to include a hyphen between the two nouns. In mathematics there are several similar objects called group action, group algebra, group ring, all of which are compound nouns but none of which is hyphenated.

Comment: I'm guessing they're not hyphenated because they probably don't normally have an adjective in front of them that lends confusion to what's meant.